# actionscript 3 how to use getChildByName for button (not MovieClip)

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip

okay so I have a button (not a movie clip) called sClose. I also have a button called s and a movieclip called sMC. Basically, everything is on one frame. The code starts off by making sMC hidden and sClose hidden. Now, when you click s, sMC and sClose appear. SMC is a screen and sClose is just a close button, where if you click it, then it hides itself and it hides sMC. So basically, if sCLose is clicked, it takes you back to the original screen. Here is the actionscript 3 cpde.

```
sMC.visible=false;
sCLose.visible=false;
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var focus;
    var cB;
    focus = MovieCLip(getChildByName(event.target.name + "MC"));
    cB = Button(getChildByName(event.target.name + "Close"));
    focus.visible=true;
    cB.visible=true;
```

When I run the code, there is no error for the MovieClip(getChildByName) line, however, it gives an error for the Button(getChildByName) line. It says "Call to possibly undefined method Button." Why is it saying this?

Comment: Have you imported the `Button` class?

Comment: How would I do that? Just "import Button"? Because I tried that and it said "Definition Button could not be found". I figured that the button class was already there, like the MovieClass. Becasue when I type "Button" in Actionscript, it does glow blow.

Comment: Note that I don't use Flash Professional much, but assuming it's the same as pure AS3 and Flex. In your case, try putting this at the top of your code: `import fl.controls.Button;` Based on what you said in your revised comment, this probably won't help then ;)

Comment: Hm yea, still gives the same error.. It also says "fl.controls:Button could not be found"

Comment: Note that there's not supposed to be a colon between 'controls' and 'Button', but a period: `fl.controls.Button;` ... but maybe that's just what the error message says even though you may have typed it as above.

Comment: yea that's just what the output says. I couldn't solve this problem so I decided to just turn the button into a MovieCLip but now I am coming accross another error. Can you try looking over here and seeing why the error is coming?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010473/actionscript-how-to-get-name-of-instance-using-getchildbyname

Comment: You're not by any chance actually using a `SimpleButton`? That's what you get when you create a "Button" in the Flash IDE.

Comment: And you are correct! I didn't even realize it until way after but yea thanks, that was the problem, I was using a simple button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to cast it to anything except DisplayObject. You don't use any of Button's properties so if you write

```
cB = DisplayObject(getChildByName(event.target.name + "Close"));
cB.visible=true;
```

it should work.