# Actionscript how to get name of instance using getChildByName

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, movieclip

Okay so I have a MovieClip called sC and need to write a code where, if you click the button (sC) then sC will dissapear. The function needs to work for multiple buttons. What I tried was

```
sC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var self;
    self = MovieClip(getChildByName(event.target.name));
    self.visible=false;
```

Now when I try this code, it gives me an error when I click sC. It says "cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.". when I try to trace(self) it outputs "null". Is there a way where I can get the name of the instance of the object which is using the clicKHandler function and then make it's visibilty equal to false (visible=false)?

Note that when I trace(event.target.name) it says "instance127".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the variable **self** resolves to your movieClip's name, but not the complete path to where it exists.  Try setting it up like below, where **target** is the button that was clicked:

```
sC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.visible = false;
}
```